# the difference between the definition of the back camera, and IMU coordinate system of IPhone 6

Tags: ios, rotation

I'm using some computer vision algorithm  to aid the motion sensor (inertial measurements unit [IMU]) that are built on iPhone 6.

Its important to know the difference between the camera and IMU coordinate systems definition.
I'm sure that apple defines the IMU coordinate system as follow:

[image]

But I do not know how they define the x,y,z axis of the camera.
my ultimate goal is to transfer the IMU measurement to the camera coordinate system

Answer (score 0):

The trick here is to view the axis from the top and reference it to the Right rotation and notice the rotational movement of the axis. If it doesn't rotate it's positive. If it rotates check the direction of the rotation; if it rotates to the CW then it's negative CCW is positive.